# How do I switch from an unknown shell to bash?

Tags: shell

I was surprised that I didn't find this question already on the site. So, today `$` came up after I logged in as a new user. This was unexpected because my main user's prompt starts with `username@computername:~$`.

So, how do I switch from this other shell to bash?

Comment: Just because `$` came up rather than `username@computername:~$` doesn't mean it wasn't bash. The exact formatting of the prompt is set by the PS1 variable, which can be set up or customized differently for different users.

Comment: @mouche Re: @frabjous `echo $SHELL` to find out what your current shell is.

Comment: @mouche @frabjous and beginning with a $ is actually common for bash, some non bash shells like zsh use the % out of the box, I believe other shells use other things.

Comment: @xeno it was /bin/sh and something I tried to do didn't work like it would in BASH.

Comment: @mouche being `/bin/sh` often doesn't mean much that's usually a symlink to something else. I'd type `ls -l /bin/sh` to see what it's a symlink to. In some cases being a symlink to something changes its behavior, I don't think bash is that way.

Comment: Oh, I never knew @xenoterracide. On my machine, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`.

Comment: @xenoterracide - Using `bash` as `/bin/sh` *disables* many bash features (it goes into POSIX compliance mode).

Comment: As Chris Down says, [`bash` does behave differently in some ways when it sees it's been invoked as `sh`](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). It [acts as though `--norc` was passed](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) and it [enters POSIX mode](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming the unknown shell supports running an absolute command, you could try: `/bin/bash`

To change the default shell, I would use `chsh(1)`. Sample usage: `chsh -s /bin/bash $USER`

Comment: Does chsh permanently change the shell or just for the current session?

Comment: @mouche Permanently; it changes your entry in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @mouche, `chsh(1)` will only allow to change to a shell that is listed in `/etc/shells` (and is available, presumably). `chsh -l` lists the alternatives. Be careful, some (like `nologin`) are defined for accounts that should never be used to login (nice way to lock yourself out), there might be local additions for special uses.

Answer (score 20):

You type in `bash`. If you want this to be a permanent change the default shell to `/bin/bash` by editing `/etc/passwd`.

Here's some snippets from my `/etc/passwd`:

```
avahi:x:84:84:Avahi daemon:/:/bin/false
xenoterracide:x:1000:100::/home/xenoterracide:/bin/zsh
postgres:x:88:88::/var/lib/postgres:/bin/zsh
bob:x:1001:1001::/home/bob:/bin/bash
usbmux:x:140:140:usbmux user:/:/sbin/nologin
```

The very last field contains the shell, Modifying the field after the last `:` to a valid or invalid shell will work. `/bin/false` and `/sbin/nologin` both mean the user doesn't have a real login shell, although if pam is not set up right this doesn't mean they can't login (I reported a bug on this in Arch Linux, because you can login graphically without having a login shell). `/bin/bash` and `/bin/zsh` are both valid shells, see `/etc/shells` for a list of valid shells on your systems. Here's my `/etc/shells` if you're interested.

```
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/ksh
/bin/zsh
/bin/dash
```

Yes you can use `chsh` or `usermod` to do the same things, please remember these are just structured text files, and TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: You probably want to use `chsh` instead of manually editing `passwd`

Comment: @Michael there are about 5 (POOMA) different ways to change the shell in `/etc/passwd` I didn't feel like listing any of them, because I always do it manually. chsh and usermod can both do it.

Comment: Messing around with configuration files is a Bad Idea(TM), an error might make the system unusable. Yes, it is often the only/fastest way, but then do it with ***extreme care***.

Answer (score 16):

If **chsh** or manually editing the config won't work, but a ~/.profile script is executed at login, add this line:

```
exec /bin/bash --login
```

Comment: After looking around for a while, this was the solution I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Great idea, specially if the shell selected sources that file on startup...

Comment: `touch ~/.bash_profile` or otherwise bash will exec itself in a loop: bash takes `~/.profile` in case `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist.